# How to batch parse (e.g., extract specific textual elements) a directory of .html files then add each element to a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

Suppose I have a directory of .html files -- each of which is structured identically, although each has different content contained within the tags. Each .html file is essentially a news article in which I use BeautifulSoup to extract the date, author(s), article text, source, and wordcount.

The code I posted below is what I have developed to achieve this and seems to work fine.

However, I need to accomplish two things: first, I need the script to be able to batch process an entire directory of .html files instead of opening one at a time. Second, I need to append all the extracted data into a pandas data frame (that I will eventually write to a .csv).

For context, I have roughly 3,000 .html files (news articles) to process.

Any help with this would be much appreciated! Thanks for your time.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"), "html.parser")

date = soup.select('span.display-date')[0].text.strip()

title = soup.select('h1.document-view__title')[0].text.strip()

article = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"document-view__body document-view__body--ascii"})
for x in article:
    print(x.find('p').text)

author = soup.select('span.author')[0].text.strip()

source = soup.select('span.source')[0].text.strip()

wordcount = soup.select('span.word-count')[0].text.strip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guess what you want to do without example data but do this.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pandas_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.html'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser")
    new_data_frame = process_soup(s)
    pandas_list.append(new_data_frame)

final_data_frame = pd.concat(pandas_list)
```

I'm going to assign you the following as a homework assignment:

```
def process_soup(s):
    data = {'author': s.select('span.author')[0].text.strip(),
            'source': s.select('span.source')[0].text.strip()}
    return pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
```

Complete with whatever else you want to extract out.

Comment: Hello, here is a sample of my data. https://pastebin.com/ZAyTFYfW -- I want to extract the author, article title, date, source, and article text. I am able to do that with the code I posted above, I am just not sure how to iterate over every file in my directory and then assign the author variable to something like df['author'] for the pandas data frame.

Comment: This worked! I just had to replace 's' with 'soup' in your code.

Answer (score 1):

**[Use `pool.map` to incorporate `mutlithreading` into your logic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/10011520)**

In this example, a `pool` of `10 threads` is created. U can increase the number based on your machine specs.

*Also note that I couldn't figure out the architecture of the article field, but this is immaterial to the general concept anyway*.

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from os import walk

pool = ThreadPool(10)

# update: to get all html files in a directory instead of feeding them to the script
htmls = []
for root, dirs, files in walk('./directory_containing_html_files'):
  for file in files:
    if r'.*\.html'.match(file):
      htmls.append(file)

# htmls = [
#   'file1.html',
#   'file2.html',
#   'file3.html'
#    ...
#   ]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'title', 'author', 'source', 'wordcount'])
data_list = []

def crawl_html(html_file):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_file), 'html.parser')
  data_list.append({
    'date':           soup.select('span.display-date')[0].text.strip()
    'title':          soup.select('h1.document-view__title')[0].text.strip()
    'author':         soup.select('span.author')[0].text.strip()
    'source':         soup.select('span.source')[0].text.strip()
    'wordcount':      soup.select('span.word-count')[0].text.strip()
  })

results = pool.map(crawl_html, htmls)

print(df.append(data_list))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: In this solution, do I have to specify every single one of my .html filenames?

Comment: u can give python a directory and scan the files inside it, will update my answer with an example

Comment: This might seem like it processes multiple things at a time, but because of GIL in python, it will be processing one at a time. You can better try spawning as a separate process and try comparing the performance of both.